# values are not inserting into database from servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am trying to develop a simple registration form , i have designed it in HTML and for business logic i used servlet but the values are not inserting into the database. Below is the html and servlet file.. Advance thanks those who resolve.

Register.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Register form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Patient">
    PID:<input type="text" name="pid" /><br/>
    Title:<input type="text" name="title" /><br/>
    First Name:<input type="text" name="firstname" /><br/>
    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastname" /><br/>
    Birthday:<input type="date" name="dob" /><br/>
    Address:<input type="text" name="address" /><br/>
    E-Mail:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
    Contact Number:<input type="text" name="contact"/><br/>
    Gender: 
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" checked> Male
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
            <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other<br><br>
  Occupation:<input type="text" name="occupation"/><br/>
  Age:<input type="text" name="age"/><br/>

  <label>Spouse/Parent/Legal Guardian Details</label><br>

  Name:<input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
  E-Mail:<input type="email" name="email2"/><br/>
  Address:<input type="text" name="address2"/><br/>
  Contact:<input type="text" name="phone"/><br/>
  Relation:<input type="text" name="relation"/><br/>
  Occupation:<input type="text" name="occupation2"/><br/>
  Age Group:<input type="text" name="agegroup"/><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" />
    </form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Servlet.java

```
import java.io.*; 
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class Patient extends HttpServlet {

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse         response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("Started");
        String pid = request.getParameter("pid");
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
        String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
        String dob = request.getParameter("dob");
        String address = request.getParameter("address");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String contact = request.getParameter("contact");
        String gender = request.getParameter("gender");
        String occupation = request.getParameter("occupation");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email2 = request.getParameter("email2");
        String address2 = request.getParameter("address2");
        String phone = request.getParameter("phone");
        String relation = request.getParameter("relation");
        String occupation2 = request.getParameter("occupation2");
        String agegroup = request.getParameter("agegroup");

        try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      Connection      con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/copd","root","root");
       PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into tbl_patient values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, pid);
        ps.setString(2, title);
        ps.setString(3, firstname);
        ps.setString(4, lastname);
        ps.setString(5, dob);
        ps.setString(6, address);
        ps.setString(7, email);
        ps.setString(8, contact);
        ps.setString(9, gender);
        ps.setString(10, occupation);
        ps.setString(11, age);
        ps.setString(12, name);
        ps.setString(13, email2);
        ps.setString(14, address2);
        ps.setString(15, phone);
        ps.setString(16, relation);
        ps.setString(17, occupation2);
        ps.setString(18, agegroup);

        int i=ps.executeUpdate();


        if(i>0)
        {
            out.println("Record has been inserted");
        }
        else
        {
            out.println("Failed to insert the data");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception se)
    {
       se.printStackTrace();
    }
        finally{}
     out.println("ended");
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens during the DB part?

Comment: Any exceptions, logs, stack traces?

Comment: @Dave Newton & Marvin--- Nothing , page is running successfully but values are not inserting in database and no errors at all.

Comment: Then you'll need to debug. I'm always skeptical of not being explicit about column names, since we don't know the table schema it's impossible to know if that's an issue. I don't know what the JDBC driver does if that fails. If it's *actually* doing nothing, e.g., not even printing (you should be logging, not writing random strings to the output writer) then your code isn't even being called.

Comment: All the column names are correct ...

Comment: Ya not even printing the else part also

Comment: Do you see the "ended" print?

Comment: @pelit mamani ya I can see

Answer (score 0):

Given that your servlet is activated ("finally" is printed), I can only see 3 options:

1. Most importantly: close the connection. That would be important even if you didn't have this missing data problem. By closing, you both 'commit' and prevent a leak. For a quick test it's enough that after "ps.executeUpdate" you'll add "con.close()" (In the longer consider putting it in the 'finally' clause).
2. A less likely option is that there was an exception but you don't see it, so please check all log files of your container
3. And also a thousand apologies for this silly suggestion, but could you double-check that you're looking into the correct database/table/etc...  at least personally I made such silly mistakes in complex environments ;)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions ... I will recheck and get back to you ... :)

Comment: Sorry, I just had another question: do you see any of the printouts "Record has been inserted" or "Failed to insert the data" ? thanks

Comment: Nothing is inserting ... I can see only white web page (blank web page)

Comment: Sorry, correction - can I just make sure you've also checked the system error, because the exception is not written to the browser page...

Comment: Oh.. no I cannot see printouts also

Comment: If i were in your shoes, I would try testing this JDBC logic without the servlet. It's easy to make it a standalone "public static void main" ( replacing the 'getParameter' with constants e.g. String pid = "123", and replacing 'out.println" with "System.out.println").

Comment: The reason is, I'm afraid your container could be somehow 'swallowing' the exception message, throwing it into a hard to find log, neglecting to flush, etc... a standalone 'main' is more reliable, and also easier to run with a debugger... obviously just for testing and then the Servlet can return.